# How to get native camera stream?

Tags: android, stream, camera, native

I recently started developing app on Android that will give chance to stream video to PC. But, as I read in the Internet, MediaRecorder is not the best way to do this, and some people says that native camera access is needed. But how get it work? I read some tutorials on how to develop native code but camera stream is something pro. Can anyody help? Some hellpful pages/tutorials/examples

Comment: did you got any solution regarding??

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/devnet/docs#/api/s3eapidocumentation/s3ecamera.html

Had no idea airplaySDK is now called marmalade (WTF???)

Due to the new license changes I cannot in goodwill recommend you opt for marmelade, the new licensing model is just idiotic.

Comment: So this is kind of native code generator? I wanted to start develop native camera on my own but I will try this :)

Comment: this will produce native arm code. the difference is that you use c++ instead of object-c or java... but since you had to go native you always had to go with C++. The airplaySDK simply provides a set of APIs that allow you to write once a deploy to many devices as native.